# SpreadsheetApp how to return unique values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the function I made. The var `myArray` is a list of names. I'm not able to get only unique values from this array and set it to another sheet. I just want the names once.

```
function array() {          
      var app = SpreadsheetApp;
      var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
      var destinationSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test2");

      var myArray = ss.getRange(2,1,30).getValues();

      destinationSheet.getRange(2, 1, 30).setValues(myArray);   
}
```

Can someone help me to filter this array?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative approach (for Google Script)

```
function myArray() {
var ss, s, a;
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
s = ss.getSheetByName("test").getRange(2, 1, 30).getValues();
a = [];
a.push(s[0]);
for (var n = 1; n < s.length; n++) {
    if (a.join().indexOf(s[n].join()) == -1) {
        a.push(s[n])
    };
}
ss.getSheetByName("test2").getRange(2, 1, a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a);
}
```

Comment: This works great thx a lot. If you want, can you explain real quick the if statement with join() and indexOf(). I'am not sure to understand this part that i was missing moslty

Comment: @MaximeMorin-Gagnon. Sure: the join() method turns the array into a string. So the array 'a' will be converted to a string (containing all rows that are pushed into it) and the indexOf will check if the current row (in the loop), converted to a string by the join() method, is part of that 'larger' string (a).

Comment: If this helped, please upvote or accept the answer given.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript Arrays have the method `from` using which you can create an array form a set of values, be it `String`, `Map` or `Set`.

Add this after the definition of `myArray` in your code

```
myArray = Array.from(new Set(myArray));
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

**OR**

You can use a simple `forEach` loop to filter unique values.

Assuming your array contains names only, and `getValues` returns 2-D arrays, so, your array looks something like - `[['name1', 'name2', 'name3']]`.

```
var newArray = [];
myArray.forEach(function(x){
    if(newArray.indexOf(x[0]) === -1){
        newArray.push(x[0]);
    }                   
});
```

Comment: I got this error message when i put that: TypeError: Fonction from introuvable dans l'objet function Array() { [native code for Array.Array, arity=1] }. It looks like google sheet not recognize method from

Comment: @MaximeMorin-Gagnon can you please copy and paste the error message? I couldn't understand what is written.

Comment: TypeError: Fonction from introuvable dans l'objet function Array() { [native code for Array.Array, arity=1] }. (ligne 9, fichier "Code")

Comment: can you post the variable `myArray`'s inital value, without using the `from` function?

Comment: @MaximeMorin-Gagnon Please see the alternative approach, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @JPV's answer, which is nearly perfect, but does not account for the instance that "ab" follows "abc". In this case the code would not recognize "ab" as a new instance. To get that you'd need to change the code to the following:

```
function countDistinct() {

var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ss = sh.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var length = ss.getLastRow()
var data = ss.getRange(1,1,length,1).getValues();
var a = [];
var b = 0;

for (var n = 0; n<length; n++) {

if (a.indexOf(data[n].join()) == -1) {

  a.push(data[n].join());
  b++;

  }
}

Logger.log(a);
Logger.log(b);

}
```

Variable b would give you the number of unique values, while a would just print the array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array contains names only, and getValues returns 2-D arrays, so, your array looks something like - [['name1', 'name2', 'name3']].
Assuming your array contains names only, and getValues returns 2-D arrays, so, your array looks something like - [['name1', 'name2', 'name3']].

```
var newArray = [];
myArray.forEach(function(x){
    if(newArray.indexOf(x[0]) === -1){
        newArray.push(x[0]);
    }                   
});
```

what should i do i have 2 values in array ?

what should i do if have 2 values in array ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).