# Find Next Unique Value and add formulas to next two columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to I change the recorded macro in a way that it will

1. find the next unique value in column A.
2. Go to that row
3. In Column C of that row paste formula `=transpose(filter($AZ#:$BS#,$AZ#:$BS#<>""))` In column D of that row paste `=transpose(filter($F#:$Y#,$F#:$Y#<>""))` and Column E `=transpose(filter($BW#:$CP#,$BW#:$CP#<>""))`

---

I am trying to write a Macro on Google Sheets that will find the next unique name in Column A and then apply Formula 1 to Column C, Formula 2 to Column D, Formula 3 to column E of the row where that next unique value is at.

I recorded the macro of what I did manually but would really love to not do that since I have about 2,000 unique names to do it to.

```
function threeformulas() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=transpose(filter($AZ2:$BS2,$AZ2:$BS2<>""))');
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=transpose(filter($F2:$Y2,$F2:$Y2<>""))');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=transpose(filter($BW2:$CP2,$BW2:$CP2<>""))');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C12').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2:E2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C22').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2:E2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

The transpose formulas have to be there because the database spits out reports really wonky starting in Column D to CP. Here in an image of what the data looks like. I have highlighted where the next unique value is at.[image]

Comment: What is your question? Have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets?

Comment: My question is how to I change the recorded macro in a way that it will 1st find the next unique value in column A. 2. Go to that row  3. In Column C of that row paste formula =transpose(filter($AZ#:$BS#,$AZ#:$BS#<>""))  In column D of that row paste =transpose(filter($F#:$Y#,$F#:$Y#<>"")) and Column E =transpose(filter($BW#:$CP#,$BW#:$CP#<>""))

Comment: That is too broad for this site. Try to narrow it.

Comment: I am not sure how to narrow it down more. Is there a way that there is script to just do step 1 find the next unique value and maybe highlight it?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, I challenged to think of the solution and posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Rihco Yes. That is one way to narrow it. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to check the values of column "A".
- When the 1st unique value is found in the column "A", you want to put 3 formulas to the columns "C" to "E".

  - In your sample image, you want to put the formulas to the cells "C2:E2", "C12:E12" and "C22:E22".
- In your question, Formula 1, Formula 2 and Formula 3 are `=transpose(filter($AZ2:$BS2,$AZ2:$BS2<>""))`, `=transpose(filter($F2:$Y2,$F2:$Y2<>""))` and `=transpose(filter($BW2:$CP2,$BW2:$CP2<>""))`, respectively.

In this case, in order to achieve your goal, I use the following flow.

1. Retrieve all values from the column "A".
2. Create the range list for putting 3 formulas.
3. 3 formulas are put using the created range list.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the container-bound script of Spreadsheet. And set `sheetName`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.

  // 1. Retrieve all values from the column "A".
  // 2. Create the range list for putting 3 formulas.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const ranges = sheet
    .getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow())
    .getValues()
    .reduce((o, [a], i) => {
      if (a != o.temp) {
        o.temp = a;
        const row = i + 2
        o.f1.push(`C${row}`);
        o.f2.push(`D${row}`);
        o.f3.push(`E${row}`);
      }
      return o;
    }, {f1: [], f2: [], f3: [], temp: ""});

  // 3. 3 formulas are put using the created range list.
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges.f1).setFormulaR1C1('=transpose(filter(R[0]C52:R[0]C71,R[0]C52:R[0]C71<>""))');
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges.f2).setFormulaR1C1('=transpose(filter(R[0]C6:R[0]C25,R[0]C6:R[0]C25<>""))');
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges.f3).setFormulaR1C1('=transpose(filter(R[0]C75:R[0]C94,R[0]C75:R[0]C94<>""))');
}
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [setFormulaR1C1(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setFormulaR1C1(String))

### Added:

> I guess my only question is that I am not sure how the transpose formula was changed and I was wondering how would I word it if Im referencing the data from another sheet example: transpose(filter('Raw Data-Austin'!$BW2:$CP2,'Raw Data-Austin'!BW2:$CP2<>""))

About [this your additional question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217300/find-next-unique-value-and-add-formulas-to-next-two-columns#comment113557537_64217576), in thie case, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
sheet.getRangeList(ranges.f1).setFormulaR1C1('=transpose(filter(R[0]C52:R[0]C71,R[0]C52:R[0]C71<>""))');
sheet.getRangeList(ranges.f2).setFormulaR1C1('=transpose(filter(R[0]C6:R[0]C25,R[0]C6:R[0]C25<>""))');
sheet.getRangeList(ranges.f3).setFormulaR1C1('=transpose(filter(R[0]C75:R[0]C94,R[0]C75:R[0]C94<>""))');
```

#### To:

```
sheet.getRangeList(ranges.f1).setFormulaR1C1(`=transpose(filter('Raw Data-Austin'!R[0]C52:R[0]C71,'Raw Data-Austin'!R[0]C52:R[0]C71<>""))`);
sheet.getRangeList(ranges.f2).setFormulaR1C1(`=transpose(filter('Raw Data-Austin'!R[0]C6:R[0]C25,'Raw Data-Austin'!R[0]C6:R[0]C25<>""))`);
sheet.getRangeList(ranges.f3).setFormulaR1C1(`=transpose(filter('Raw Data-Austin'!R[0]C75:R[0]C94,'Raw Data-Austin'!R[0]C75:R[0]C94<>""))`);
```

- In this modification, please be careful that the template literal is used.

Comment: Wow that works like a charm! I guess my only question is that I am not sure how the transpose formula was changed and I was wondering how would I word it if Im referencing the data from another sheet example: ***transpose(filter('Raw Data-Austin'!$BW#:$CP#,'Raw Data-Austin'!BW#:$CP#<>""))*** @Tanaike

Comment: @Rihco Thank you for replying. About your additional question, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editing the recorded macro I think that it's better to start from scratch, as Tanaike's did on [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64217576/1595451), because the recorded macros activates each cell to be edited but that will make your "macro" slow and more important that is not necesary.

So, the first thing that you should know is that Google Apps Script use JavaScript. Tanaike's answer use several interesting programming stuff like :

- varibles
- method chaining
- template literal
- Array.prototype.reduce

and some specific Spreadsheet Service features like

- Range List
- R1C1 formula notation

If you haven't done yet, read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Related

- [SpreadsheetApp how to return unique values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47625755/1595451)

Comment: Thank you for your additional information. I think that it will be useful for a lot of users.

Comment: @Rubén thank you I will take a look at it !

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for adding those references I was already able to understand how you setFormulaR1C1(formula).