# google app script how to count an array and show summary unique values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, array-formulas, array-filter

in this post [google app script i have a question how to count a duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72267467/google-app-script-i-have-a-question-how-to-count-a-duplicate-values)

I want to enter a numeral in G2:G3 (source sheet) and want to show a unique count values in B2:B4 (destination sheet) what i have to do
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HN0XCLrEzlRkInIv6xFnhCFnhZabu7Y-Tz1dvYvsGQM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "source"; // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "des"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  // Retrieve source and destination sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

  // Retrieve source values and create an object for putting to the destination sheet.
  const srcValues1 = srcSheet.getRange("A1:C" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const obj1 = srcValues1[0].map((_, c) => srcValues1.map(r => r[c])).reduce((o, [h, ...v]) => (o[h] = v, o), {});
  const srcValues2 = srcSheet.getRange("F2:G" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  srcValues2.forEach(([f, g]) => {
    if (g > 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < g - 1; i++) {
        obj1[f] = [...obj1[f], ...obj1[f]];
      }
    }
  });
  const obj2 = Object.values(obj1).flat().reduce((o, a) => (o[a] = o[a] ? o[a] + 1 : 1, o), {});

  // Retrieve the values of column "A" from the destination sheet and create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange("A2:A" + dstSheet.getLastRow());
  const dstValues = dstRange.getDisplayValues().map(([a]) => [obj2[a] || 0]);

  // Put the result values to the column "B" of the destination sheet.
  dstRange.offset(0, 1).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

- From your provided Spreadsheet, the sample sheet names are `source` and `des`. Please modify this for your actual situation.
- When you run this script, the values are retrieved from the source sheet, and the groups are increased using the values from column "G", and the count of each value (`1, 2, 3`) is calculated. And, the result values are put in column "B" of the destination sheet.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the structure of the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)